# C++ String Literal Changing After Function Terminates

Tags: c++, string

I have three functions like this:

```
MyStruct foo() {
    //do something...
    return get_var("string literal");
}

MyStruct get_var(const string &literal) {
    return (MyStruct) {some_attribute, &*literal.begin(), literal.size()}; //struct needs const char*
}

void bar() {
    Mystruct var;
    //do stuff
    var = foo();
    std::cout << var.string_attribute;
}
```

This should print "string literal", but instead, the first half of the string is a random jumble of characters.
If I do this:

```
MyStruct get_var(const string &literal) {
    std::cout << literal;
    return (MyStruct) {some_attribute, &*literal.begin(), literal.size()}; //struct needs const char*
}
```

It prints correctly only the first time. and if I do this:

```
MyStruct foo() {
    //do something...
    string my_literal = "string literal";
    std::cout << my_literal;
    return get_var(my_literal);
}
```

It prints correctly the first and second times, but not the third. I have no idea what's happening; I thought string literals lasted forever, so it shouldn't be overwritten or anything.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The correct way to get a `const char*` from `literal` is to use `literal.c_str()` instead of `&*literal.begin()`. But since you did not show what `MyStruct` looks like or what it does with the `const char*`, the most likely cause of your problem is a *dangling pointer* due to `literal` being destroyed after giving the `const char*` to `MyStruct`

Comment: A dangling pointer is a good guess, but without enough code for us to reproduce the behavior, it is just a guess. Please provide a [mre] so we don't have to guess. (We're missing the definition of the `MyStruct` constructor being used. For completeness, there should also be a trimmed-down definition of `MyStruct` that declares both this constructor and `string_attribute`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c++ is an old language that grew out of C, the result is that both the behavior and the terminology used to describe that behavior can be rather confusing.

A "string literal" is a sequence of characters in the source code surrounded by quotes. In most contexts it evaluates to a pointer to a null-terminated sequence of characters (a "C string"). Under normal circumstances* said sequence of characters will indeed remain valid for the entire lifetime of the progream.

The type `string` in your code on the other hand is probably referring to `std::string` (via `using namespace std` somewhere) which is a class representing an automatically managed string

When you do `get_var("string literal");` or `string my_literal = "string literal";` the "C string" is implicitly converted to a `std::string`. This operation creates a **copy** of the sequence of characters. Unlike the original sequence of characters this sequence of characters will be freed when the `std::string` that owns it is destroyed.

&*literal.begin is a somewhat unorthadox way to get a pointer to the sequence of characters owned by the std::string. using c_str would be more normal. That isn't relevant to your problem though. The important bit is the sequence of characters in memory is one owned by the std::string, not the original sequence from the string literal.

In the case of `get_var("string literal");` the std::string is destroyed as soon as the statement completes. In the case of `string my_literal = "string literal";` it is destroyed when the variable `my_literal` goes out of scope. Either way it is destroyed before `foo()` returns. So when you do `std::cout << var.string_attribute;` you are referencing a stale pointer for which the associated memory has already been freed.

<s>The reason it works "sometimes" is that memory managers do not generally overwrite memory as soon as it is freed. Typically the memory is not actually overwritten until something re-uses it.</s>

Edit: misread your question. It is possible for a use-after free to "work" sometimes but that is not what is going on here. The cout calls you say are working are at points in the code where the std::string is still alive.

* Excluding cases like unloading shared libraries at runtime that are beyond the scope of the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

Enable maximum compiler warnings. It should alert you to the fact that you're trying to return a pointer to a temporary.

The line `string my_literal = "string literal";` creates a string, then passes a const reference to that string into the function. Then at the end of `foo()`, `my_literal` is **DESTROYED**. It is **GONE**. Any pointers to that are now **INVALID**.

Absolutely any bad thing can happen after that, it is undefined behavior.